# Play framework: how to monitor number of active sessions with standard session API?

Tags: scala, playframework

In Play framework there is an API to create a session, put some data to the session and discard the session.
But I would also like to have some insight into things like how many active sessions are currently in my installation, how many data in volume is bound to them, etc.
Are there any means to deal with this?

Comment: In Play a session is just a signed cookie with your data that is send in each request, so you don't have session data in the server side and can't know how many sessions are active. But you should be able to implement that using Akka or the cache api

Comment: @Salem, if I correctly understand then this cookie lives as long as the browser is opened, without any expiration time. How is that achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play is by stateless by nature, thus no session exists on the server to be tracked or monitored. When you use session API you just create a cookie that will be sent with every request / response from/to the browser.

This cookie doesn't have a timeout or expiration date, hence it will persist as long as the browser is open. However you can implement your own session timeout mechanism by setting a last access time on the session cookie and compare it to the desired timeout on every request.